# How can I merge two associative arrays while preserving their keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have two arrays:

```
$arr =  array('k1' => 'v1', 
              'k2' => 'v2');
$arr2 = array('k3' => 'v3', 
              'k4' => 'v4');
```

I want to merge `$arr2` into `$arr`, so that I end up with:

```
$arr =  array('k1' => 'v1', 
              'k2' => 'v2',
              'k3' => 'v3', 
              'k4' => 'v4');
```

There is one basic requirement: the solution **must** change `$arr` itself, like functions that take a reference to the array (`array_push()`, `array_splice()`) would do.

- I don't want to use `$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr2)` because it creates a copy.
- I don't want to iterate through $arr2 :

  ```
  // this is not an option
  foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v)
  {
      $arr[$k] = $v;
  }
  ```

How can I merge two associative arrays while preserving their keys?

Comment: what do you mean by `array_merge() creates a copy` ?

Comment: Why is the foreach not an option?  Is it not doing the job?

Comment: @coder1984 It does. If you do `$arr3 = array_merge($arr, $arr2)` both `$arr` and `$arr2` remain unchanged.

Comment: is this homework? there is no real need to use references in php for arrays, just `$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr2);`

Comment: @quantumSoup but you are overriding the value of `$arr` when you do `$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr2)`

Comment: Hmm I don't think you can get everything ;) What's wrong with the foreach?

Comment: please look here http://codepad.org/4GDL6WAH, `array_merge` should work fine.

Comment: @Hiroto It's not homework. Imagine I have a huge array and I don't want to have work with copies. Functions like `array_push()` change the original array.

Comment: @quantumSoup aha, so this is a size issue, and you can't iterate over it in a foreach? You should add that to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$arr += $arr2;
```

I've tested memory usage:

```
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) $a[]=1;
echo memory_get_peak_usage(), "\n";
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) $b[]=1;
echo memory_get_peak_usage(), "\n";
$a += $b;
echo memory_get_peak_usage(), "\n";
```

This outputs:

```
209135144
417540744
417540872
```

So while one array with 1 M elements uses about 200 MB, and the overall peak is about 400 MB, PHP apparently did not create a copy, otherwise the peak memory would be around 600 MB (`$a`, `$b` and `$a + $b`).

Comment: PHP creates references when copying, and only creates a separate value on the first write. So if you add the two arrays and delete the second, the memory used will not grow, because there is nothing to copy anymore.

Comment: The one downside to this approach is if there are conflicting array keys the keys in $arr win out over $arr2... which is the opposite behaviour of `array_merge`. If this doesn't matter however... no worries :)

Comment: @Sven: I know "copy on write", but I assumed the + operator being a write.

Comment: Curiously if you do `$a = $a + $b` instead of `$a += $b` the peak increases to about 550 MB.

Comment: @Wolfgang: Yes, write to itself. We have two arrays of 200MB each, combined 400MB. The first array of 200MB gets replaced with the combined array, using references to the values in the second array. If you write to every array value in the first array, you'll end up with 600MB, because the second array retains its values.

Comment: @Sven: Actually we have 2 M values (ZVALs), no matter what we do. The difference must be caused by the memory the array hash table uses.

Comment: Is this still the way to "`array_merge` by reference" in 2017?

Comment: Also I verified that with += reference to the array itself, and references to any items within are maintained - which is super cool - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/911f10fca3f7e689cb1fc4b52b56a5e9